# ByteArrayOutputStream with zipStream to InputStream

Tags: java, zip, inputstream, outputstream

Currently I want to create a zip file and make it available in the browser via HTTP response. Because I don't want to cache files on the hard disk I have to use streams all the time. The problem is that after creating the zip file I only have one ByteArrayOutputStream, but for sending the response I need an InputStream.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
// filling zip with multiple ZipEntrys

IOUtils.closeQuietly(zip);
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
IOUtils.closeQuietly(baos);
```

The line

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
```

gives me a null pointer every time.

What is wrong? Is there a stream not completely written? Additionally I have to do everything with Java 6 and Apache commons.

Comment: If you get an `NPE` on that line, then `baos` is `null`. If you're reading the stacktrace correctly and in fact are getting an `NPE` from *that* line.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - and if you can do that without using the Apache libraries, that would help too. (If you're just using them for IOUtils, just call close and declare that your method might throw IOException.)

Comment: It was my fault, sometimes it helps to read the stacktrace correctly. I had tried to set the name of the zip file with zip.write("test.zip".getBytes());. But this does not seem to be the correct way, so I ended up here in the catch.